# ExecuteStreamCommand requires file in all machines

Tags: hadoop, etl, apache-nifi, execute

i have two node nifi cluster and i  have a scenario that i need to run the bash script to connect to database. now file is available in one machine and when i run this it returns error like `cannot run program./zz.sh (in directory /home/nifi/test/) no such file or directory.`

i created  test directory in all two machines under /home/nifi and i have enough permissions.
now i created zz.sh file in one of the nifi instance(non primary node) and gave 777 permission.

my flow:

```
generateflowfile(allnodes) --> executestreamcommand
```

i tried like create zz.sh file only in primary node and set run on primary node only in generatedataflow it works fine.

but i need to workout this as generateflowfile(allnodes).

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, you created the script on both nodes and it didn't work?

Comment: @BryanBende if i place file in both machines, file executed in both machines. but i want execute on only one machine

Comment: So put the script the on both machines but set GenerateFlowFile to run on only primary node, the script needs to be on both nodes so that ExecuteStreamCommand can be considered valid and be started, but it will only receive a flow file on primary node so it won't do anything on the other